# Can I Use Background Images in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, outlook, background-image

I know there are a lot of posts about this on Stackoverflow already, but none of the solutions suggested seem to be working. I'm trying to add a background to a table cell in an email blast. I can't get it to appear in Outlook. It's content, so it should probably be HTML, but then I have issues with padding. What is the best way to achieve this effect on all major email clients?

Thank you!

```html
<table style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" cellpadding="0px">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
       <td background="http://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/rogersparkfoodcoop/mailings/127/attachments/original/lannin.jpg?1469496240" bgcolor="#2594aa" width="290" height="290" valign="top">
      <div>
        &nbsp;
       </div>
       <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
        </v:rect>
       <![endif]-->
       </td>
       <td style="background-color:#c8d300; width:290px;" width="290px">
       <table cellpadding="4px">
        <tr>
        <td>
         <p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, serif; color:#FFF; font-size:11px; line-height:1.2">I believe in the principles around which the RP Food Co-op is organized that includes concern for the environment, for fair labor practices, for community, and for democratic decision-making. My husband and I invested in the co-op not only to have eventual access to its services, but also to benefit the community the co-op serves. Member shares give the co-op the capital base it needs while giving members the sense of ownership. Patronage refunds, based on how much the owners use the co-op, reduce the co-op's tax obligations and keep more money circulating in the local economy. The co-op offers a way to build community through the relationships it builds between the food producers, shoppers, co-op members, volunteers, and employees.</p>
        
         <p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, serif; color:#FFF; font-size:11px; font-style:italic;">-Sue Lannin, Owner #147
         </p>
        </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
       </td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Please re-format your html code

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, I was able to do this with simple `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` using an image of the correct dimensions. It doesn't scale fluidly, but it doesn't have to.